# Доступ к нескольким репозиториям github по одному ключу ssh

Tags: github

Создал на github второй репозиторий. Настраиваю к нему доступ по ключу ssh.

При попытке добавить ключ система говорит мне, что такой ключ уже есть. Такой ключ действительно уже используется, но в первом репозитории.

Я что-то не так делаю, или github действительно не позволяет доступ к двум репозиториям по одному ключу?

Я понимаю, что это ограничение достаточно легко обходится, более того, я уже сделал доступ ко второму репозиторию по другому ключу. Но не удобно же. Да и какой смысл в таком ограничении?

Comment: есть ключи репозитория и есть общие ключи в профиле, ключи в профиле действуют для всех ваших репозиториев -
 https://github.com/settings/keys

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра проверю.

Comment: Ключ привязывается к аккаунту, а не к репозиторию

Comment: в репозиториях есть `Deploy keys` для доступа к конкретному проекту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За ответ спасибо пользователю @diproart:

> есть ключи репозитория и есть общие ключи в профиле, ключи в профиле действуют для всех ваших репозиториев - github.com/settings/keys